# Live search showing "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known" error

Tags: php, ajax, search

I'm hosting a "live search" downloaded from [here](http://ajaxlivesearch.com/).

I followed the instructions given in the website.

I'm getting the following error now:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

My website is [here.](http://versatalis.net)

I've did an intensive search and found that it is a problem with DNS server.

But, I don't know how to work that out. Please help me.

The code of `process_livesearch.php`

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://versatalis.net');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header_remove('X-Powered-By');

file_exists(realpath(__DIR__ .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'handler.php')) ? require_once(realpath(__DIR__ .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'handler.php')) : die('There is no such a file: handler.php');

// 1. Validate all inputs
$errors = Handler::validate_input($_POST);
if (count($errors) === 0)
{
    // 2. A layer of security against those Bots that submit a form quickly
    if (Handler::verify_bot_searched($_POST['ls_page_loaded_at']))
    {
        // 3. Verify the token - CSRF protection
        if (Handler::verify_session_value('token', $_POST['ls_token']) && Handler::verify_session_value('anti_bot' ,$_POST['ls_anti_bot']))
        {
            // 4. Start looking for the query
            $result = json_encode(Handler::get_result($_POST['ls_query'], (int) $_POST['ls_current_page'], (int) $_POST['ls_items_per_page']));

            // 5. Return the result
            Handler::form_response('success', 'Successful request', $result);
        }
        else
        {
            // Tokens are not matched
            Handler::form_response('failed', 'Error: Please refresh the page. It seems that your session is expired.');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Searching is started sooner than the search start time offset
        Handler::form_response('failed', 'Error: You are too fast, or this is a Bot. Please search now.');
    }
}
else
{
    // Required inputs are not provided
    Handler::form_response('failed', "Error: Required or invalid inputs: " . implode(',', $errors));
}
```

Comment: Please provide searching process code in `process_livesearch.php`?

Comment: @kupendra - I've added the code in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Since you're getting an SQL error, the problem probably lies in the code that attempts to connect to the DB.

Comment: @AliAkram Check your `config.php` to configure properly??

Comment: Thanks @kupendra and Patrick Q - Yeah, there was a typo error in 'config.php'. But, after correcting that, weirdly I'm getting '500 Internal Server Error'. So, helpless. Thanks.

Comment: For the 500 error, check your error logs. There should be something in there that points you in the right direction (or that you could add to your question).

Comment: @PatrickQ - PHP Fatal error:  `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'' in /home/versa66/public_html/class/handler.php:85.`. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: That error is pretty self-explanatory. You're executing a query on a table where you're referencing an `id` column, but that table does not have an `id` column. Find (and fix) the query (possibly on line 85 of handler.php or fix your table.

Comment: @PatrickQ and kupendra - That worked like a charm. Thanks folks.